# Unable to create RecyclerView inside AlertDialog, content inside Alert Dialog is blank

Tags: java, android

I am trying to display two RecyclerViews inside alert dialog contents. Please Help what am I doing wrong?

The onCreateViewHolder function is not being called

Please note that the RecyclerViews are inside the ConstraintLayout in the xml. If that is causing them not to display what should be the correct procedure?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private View inflatedView;
private RecyclerView fontList,sizeList;
private String[] fonts = {"normal","sans","serif","monospace"};
private String[] sizes = {"14","16","18","20","22","24"};

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    inflatedView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.design_style,null);

    builder.setView(inflatedView).setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"OK Pressed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }).setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Cancel",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.show();

    fontList = inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.fontlist);
    sizeList = inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.sizelist);

    fontList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    fontList.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(Arrays.asList(fonts)));

    sizeList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    sizeList.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(Arrays.asList(sizes)));

}

private class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder>{

    private List<String> itemList;

    public MyAdapter(List<String> itemList) {
        this.itemList = itemList;
        Log.d("lol","MyAdapter");
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.design_fontcell,viewGroup);
        Log.d("lol","onCreateViewHolder");
        return new MyViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyAdapter.MyViewHolder myViewHolder, int i) {
        myViewHolder.mtextView.setText(itemList.get(i));
        Log.d("lol",itemList.get(i));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        Log.d("lol","getItemCount: "+itemList.size());
        return itemList.size();
    }

    class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        TextView mtextView;
        MyViewHolder(View cellView){
            super(cellView);
            mtextView = cellView.findViewById(R.id.textView_font);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: try using LinearLayout

Comment: @Vishal yes it works with linear layout, why not with constraints?

Answer (score 0):

**Change your code like this**

```
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    inflatedView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.design_style,null);

     //No need of setView() for buttons
    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"OK Pressed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }).setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Cancel",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    fontList = inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.fontlist);
    sizeList = inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.sizelist);

    fontList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    fontList.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(Arrays.asList(fonts)));

    sizeList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    sizeList.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(Arrays.asList(sizes)));

    builder.setView(inflatedView); //Set the view at the end

    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.show();
```